# Separation of Variables PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am given $u_t$ = $u_{xx} - au$ where a is a nonzero constant, $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $u(0,t)=0$, and $u(1,t)=0$. Solve the time dependent problem via separation of variables method when a>0.

I let $u(x,t)=P(t)Q(x)$ and plugged that into the equation. I got
$$
\frac {P'}P=\frac {Q''}Q-a
$$ and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have further questions on my answer?

Comment: Nope I got it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, in that case, and if it fully answers you question, don't hesitate to mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hint

$$
u = X(x)T(t) \implies u_t = T'X,\ u_{xx} = TX'' \implies T'X = TX'' - aXT \implies \frac {T'}T = \frac {X''}X - a
$$
LHS is the function of $t$ only, RHS is the function of $x$ only, so this identity to be true, you need to require, that they are the same constant.
$$
\frac {T'}T = \frac {X''}X - a = \lambda
$$

Comment: So even though there is -a it is still lamda regardless?

Comment: @3141 they are independent from each other. If you had some function in there, then it'd be different, but since $a = const$, then yes, it won't change the fact that RHS is the function of $x$ only.